# Handling nested transactions in a OOP application

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm thinking about designing a new application and stumbled upon a generic question about nested transaction. I've some objects I need to reuse. Suppose one of this object is

```
class A {
    public method(){
        $db->startTransaction(); // shared $db object
        // .... do a lot of SQL work
        $db->commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

Suppose now that there is a second object B that needs to call A->method and rollback all if an error occurs as in:

```
class B {
    public anotherMethod(){
        $db->startTransaction();
        $a = new A();
        $a->method();
        // code that throws an error
        $db->rollbackTransaction();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to handle such situations? Is there a best practice that you follow?

Comment: I suppose you are aware that MySQL does not support nested transactions and just want suggestions on how to handle that.

Comment: Yes I know that! The question is how can one handle that (is it even possible?) without changing the old objects.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesnt support nested Transactions, However you can still use savepoints

Comment: I know that. Imagine that A object is like a black box. I couldn't even know it uses a transaction in the worst scenario. How you take care of such situations?